# Adding Margins to Prototype Cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

How can I add top, bottom, left, and right margin spacings between each individual prototype cell in UITableView? (storyboard) Seems there are different solutions for different versions of iOS and none for swift yet.

#### Current Cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OptionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.options[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
       
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set margins between cells, but you can make it look like there are margins by giving the cell a clear background color, and adding a subview (to which you would add any other subviews you need) that is inset from the edges of the cell by whatever margins you want. Give this view a background color, and turn off the cell separators. This can all be done in IB with no code if you choose.